# Unable to click submit button in selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath, testng

I am working in a travel application. Once i filled the details like origin, destination i have to click the submit button. I tried with the xpath to click the submit button. But, i am unable to submit. Application is loading internally,once it clicks the xpath of submit. Please refer screen shot.

Selenium code: java   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']")).click();

Please check image
[Submitbutton- xpath code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrrga.png)

Comment: Why you are using xpath even if element id is available ?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML for the button. Is it inside an IFRAME? What happens when your code runs? Are there errors? If so, post the entire error.

Comment: Hi Jeff , nothing is happening when i run the code. It is adding the travel and destination, but finally i want to click the submit button. But, i cant. please refer the HTML code in the next comment

Comment: There are three button,  save, submit, reset and i want to click the submit button. HTML code is -->HTML for submit button:

HTML CODE FOR SUBMIT BUTTON: <input id="ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit" class="fadbtn" type="submit" style="color:Black;border-style:None;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return AdvanceValidation();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$TravelRequest1$btnSubmit", "", true, "vgReqSubmit", "", false, false))" value="Submit" name="ctl00$cphMain$TravelRequest1$btnSubmit"/> .... Below is the xpath for the submit button

Answer (score 1):

can you please provide your html code for this issue,
there must be  element present in that code,
you should have to use submit() instead of clicking on submit element.

actually click() works only on submit button of  (you have to check this condition) and submit() works for all form elements and performs Enter key pressed like operations.
i hope this have to work for you,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']")).submit();
```

or try using this,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_tpTravel_travel_gvTravel_ctl02_txtDuration']")).submit();
```

according to your html code we get element by id,

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit")).submit();
```

Comment: HTML CODE FOR SUBMIT BUTTON: <input id="ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit" class="fadbtn" type="submit" style="color:Black;border-style:None;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;" onclick="return AdvanceValidation();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$cphMain$TravelRequest1$btnSubmit", "", true, "vgReqSubmit", "", false, false))" value="Submit" name="ctl00$cphMain$TravelRequest1$btnSubmit"/>    .... Below is the xpath for the submit button

Comment: Xpath for submit button is  pasted below. driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']")).click();

Comment: try with submit() ok  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']")).submit();

Comment: Hi ashish, for the previous code, i am getting the O/P as -->invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression .//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit'] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string './/[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)

Answer (score 0):

In your case, might be the submit button is visible but not clickable as you mentioned in the description. For that, you will have to wait until the element is not to be clickable using the ExplicitWait method. Perform click action after the Submit button gets clickable:

Hope below code will solve your problem.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately it is not working. Getting the below error  --->  Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: .//[@id='ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit']

Comment: Could you insert your HTML page code in your question?

Comment: Simplified your code. You were using a temporary variable when none was needed.

Comment: @bhavind. HTML code inserted. Kindly check comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the `click()` method does not work. Please try with below code once and let me know.

```
WebElement Login=driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_cphMain_TravelRequest1_btnSubmit"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", Login);
```

Comment: Hi @Kajal.d. Thanks it is working. But the problem is , when i click submit a notification will come and i have to choose Yes or No from that Notification.  Here, when i click the submit button, notification appears, but notification disappearing immediately.